# Как удалить стандартный экземпляр БД, который ставится по умолчанию в Oracle database XpressEdition?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle11g

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу помочь разобраться в следующем: Установил Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 , после создания имени  для application Express workspace , логина и пароля создается экземпляр с таблицами по умолчанию. Прошу уточнить как можно удалить все эти таблицы быстро через консоль или каким-нибудь другим способом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста что именно вы хотите удалить - экземпляр (`DB instance`) или все таблицы (из какой схемы)?

Comment: При создании любой схемы (WorkSpace)  по умолчанию создаются таблицы,которые Вы видите на скриншоте. Вопрос состоит в том как можно быстро удалить эти таблицы (может консольная команда) или сделать так, чтобы они не создавались автоматически.